# Should a subdomain be accessible as subfolder?

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

I have a subdomain for my website created in cPanel and I've noticed that in addition to being able to access the content through this URL:

```
subdomain.example.com
```

It can also be accessed via:

```
example.com/subdomain
```

Questions:

1. Is that normal?
2. Is there any way to only allow access to the
   subdomain through, well, the subdomain?

Comment: it's normal. you can change htaccess so it only allows the subdomain to access that folder

Comment: What I mostly do is just make a folder beside the `public_html` folder (in the `~/` path). They only thing you have to do is change your subdomain's path in cPanel to point to that folder. This I also do because Mercurial repositories don't like repositories to exist inside other repositories, so checking them out that way doesn't go that well ;). I guess for some people it's normal to have it as a subfolder inside the www folder tho :P

Comment: @Allendar can you do that on a normal shared hosting account or you have host ur own or VPS? Please share i tried it and i got 403 forbidden

Comment: You should be able to tweak it in your `hosts` file. If you are uncertain you might want to contact your hosting company. They can probably easily answer that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it as long as either you don't send users to the directory, or the applications and pages in that directory can handle using two different URLs (e.g. it uses only relative URLs).

If you want to block the directory, then try this htaccess directive:
`RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L,R=404]`